# Mesh Tool - Edge Offset

Tags: edit-mode

Is there a way to improve the resolution of curve B?

I have performed an edge offset via add-on Mesh tools of curve A to get Curve B but there are too few vertices.

I would like these highlighted regions to be more rounded. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can select the part you want to be more rounded, subdivide it so you have more geometry to work with.
Then scale it by 0 on the X axis so you have a straight line, select the vertex in the center of this line and move it back along the X axis with proportional editing activated to get a smooth curve.